Celery Task is not registered
I am Trying to Run the function through Celery Task.
Both The redis and celery worker container is running
But when i hit the endpoint it will Show the error in the Logs .
the Error with Code mentioned below.
Goal:
I want somebody resolve this problem. why i am having this problem, i followed each step but could not find a solution.
or in case there is a mismatch in the configuration. provide a solution.
Error:

Docker Container Logs
Received unregistered task of type 'jina_fetch_urls_celery_task'. The message has been ignored and discarded.

scraper-legal/config/init.py
from .celery import celery as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)


scraper-legal/config/celery.py

from celery import Celery
import os

redis_url = os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://redis:6379/0")
redis_backend= os.getenv("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://redis:6379/0")
celery = Celery(
    "scraper-legal",
    broker=redis_url,
    backend=redis_backend
)

celery.conf.update(
    timezone="UTC",
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True
)
celery.autodiscover_tasks()
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     celery.start()


scraper-legal/utils/tasks.py
from config.celery import celery


@celery.task
def jina_fetch_urls_celery_task(run_id: PydanticObjectId, site: str):

scraper-legal/routes/run.py
from utils.tasks import jina_fetch_urls_celery_task

@router.post(
    "/",
    response_description="Run data added into the database",
    response_model=RunResponse,
)
async def create_run(run: Run = Body(...)):
    new_run = await add_run(run)
    task_id = str(new_run.id)
    update_data = {"task_id": task_id, "status": "in_progress", "status_description": "Fetching Data"}
    await patch_run(new_run.id, update_data)
    
    # Manually update new_run with the patch data
    for key, value in update_data.items():
        setattr(new_run, key, value)
    
    jina_fetch_urls_celery_task.delay(new_run.id, new_run.site)
    return {
        "status_code": 200,
        "response_type": "success",
        "description": "Run created successfully",
        "data": new_run,
    }


Since you use celery symbol everywhere it could be that somehow somewhere you use wrong celery. That is why I always use a meaningful name for the Celery instance. Therefore I suggest you refactor the code and have something like: capp = Celery( ... , and then annotate your tasks with @capp.task()

thanks @DejanLekic:
i change to celery_app

Did that solve the issue?

yes it works. Thank you
